# SQLite database location

Tags: android

Using Eclipse to build an Android app.  When I create/open a database (SQLite) my log indicates that its location is /data/data/package/databases/dbname.  Is there a way to access this db using one of the Windows-based SQLite managers, eg; SQLite Database Browser.  The path must be the path as it would be on the device, but I cannot find the DB on my Windows box.
Any help appreciated by this Android novice.

Answer (score 0):

you can pull out the db file using DDMS in eclipse ..

thanks sir, I forgot to mention the "emulator" above...........

these link 'll be help ful to you

[Android eclipse DDMS - Can't access data/data/ on phone to pull files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867379/android-eclipse-ddms-cant-access-data-data-on-phone-to-pull-files)

[Android Eclipse DDMS - Can't pull file from rooted device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797019/android-eclipse-ddms-cant-pull-file-from-rooted-device)

[How can I read my database from DDMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321246/how-can-i-read-my-database-from-ddms)

Comment: Only if the database is on an emulator, or possibly a rooted device. There is no way to access the database file on standard production hardware.

Comment: yes .... only on emulator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154092/reading-database-file-from-android-device

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use a BackupAgent to access the database. You can't access it from a Explorer like windows howver you can code it. See this thread for more info:

[Android backup/restore: how to backup an internal database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database)